# Background Moving Over My Object

Tags: rendering

In camera mode, my objects keep getting engulfed by the background and I do not understand what is going on...

[image]

Comment: have you checked the clipping distances (both for scene and camera)?

Comment: I just tried the clipping values and it did not change anything in the camera view.

Comment: You led me to the answer! It was not the the view-port clipping that was the answer, rather there is a clipping profile in "Object date properties" (the green camera, when the camera was selected) that allowed me to correct the clipping distances.

Comment: Yes that's why I was talking about checking the camera as well  ;)